# Invalid form key please refresh the page magento2

Tags: magento-2.1.4

Can any one help me for below issue

while saving the product iam getting :

> Invalid form key Please refresh the page

page is not saving

I was also tried by changing the `max_input_vars`

Help me great thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Please ask hosting provider to increase php_value max_input_vars 75000.

1. Remove app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php is exist.
2. Try to clear the cache from var/cache directory.
3. Then clear browser cache. Especially clear or delete cookies.

Comment: Thanks but in magento 2 no session.php

Comment: Still an issue, not fixed , I increased it to 10K and still facing the same problem